# Cohomology of a fiber bundle with fiber $H$ and base space $BG$

Tags: cohomology, fibration

Are there any general results on the (integral) cohomology 
of fiber bundle, where the fiber is a compact group $H$ (continuous or discrete)
and the base space is the classifying space $BG$ of another  compact group $G$ (continuous or discrete). Any literature references is much appreciated.

Since we have two groups $G$ and $H$. I wonder if the result can be expressed as
group cohomology of the two groups.

Comment: Serre's spectral sequence?

Comment: I wonder if the Serre's spectral sequence can be expressed in terms of group cohomology of $H$ and $G$.

Comment: Do you have in mind a definition of group cohomology that does not involve the cohomology of the classifying space?

Comment: There is an elementary definition of group cohomology without involving the topological cohomology of the classifying space. (See Wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology ) I stress group cohomology since we may need G-module where the group has non-trivial action. Using classifying space to define group cohomology with a non-trivial G-module, we may need the "local coefficient system" which I do not understand. This is why I prefer to state the results in terms of  group cohomology.

Answer (score 1):

A typical example would be the case when $G$ is a subgroup of $H$. Then $(EH\times H)/G$ (diagonal action) is 1. homotopy equivalent to $H/G$, and 2. fibered over $BG=EH/G$ with fiber $H$. Note that this works both in the Lie case and the discrete case but in the latter case what we get is not very interesting since the fiber of our fibration is a potentially infinite discrete space.

[upd: There is one thing one can extract from this though: the $i$-th cohomology group of $G$ with coefficients in the infinite product $\Pi_{h\in H}\mathbb{Z}_{(h)}$ is $\Pi_{h G\in H/G} \mathbb{Z}_{(hG)}$ when $i=0$ and is 0 otherwise; this may be of some use when $G$, or its index in $H$, is finite.]

On the other hand, if $G$ is normal in $H$ one can go a bit further: $BH=EH/H$ is the quotient of $BG=EH/G$ by a free action of $H/G$. So, as above, we construct a fibration over $B(H/G)$ with fiber $BG$ and total space $BH$. If we now take an $H$-module $M$ (i.e., a local system on $BH$) we get the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence

$$E_2^{pq}=H^p(H/G,H^q(G,M))\Rightarrow H^{p+q}(H,M).$$

There are lots of references where this is discussed. One could take a look e.g. at the original paper by Hochschild and Serre (Cohomology of group extensions, Transactions AMS 1953).

Comment: Let $X$ be the fiber bundle with fiber $H$ and base space $BG$. I wonder do we have:
$E_2^{pq}=H_g^p(H,H_g^q(G,M))\Rightarrow H^{p+q}(X,M)$ ?

Comment: Xiao-Gang -- there are potentially lots of fiber bundles with fiber $H$ and base $BG$. If we have one that comes from an action of $G$ on $H$, then we do have a Serre spectral sequence converging to the cohomology of the total space, which is $\sim H/G$, but its $E_2$ term looks quite different from what you describe. The Hochschild-Serre sequence has a similar (but still different) $E_2$ but converges to the cohomology of $H$.

Comment: Indeed, we are considering fiber bundles with fiber $H$ and base $BG$ that comes from an action of $G$ on $H$. But $G$ may not be a subgroup of $H$. So we do not have $H/G$.

Comment: Xiao-Gang -- re "We do not have..": yes we do, assuming the action comes from a group homomorphism $f:G\to H$, except that the action will be not free in general (and the base of the fibration will be $BIm(f)=BG/\ker(f)$).

Comment: algori: Thank you for explaining, but as a physicist, I am still confused (maybe over something simple).
Do you mean $H^*(X,M)=H^*(H/G,M)$? But if $G$ is not a subgroup of $H$, we cannot compute the quotient group $H/G$.
But do you mean $H/Im(f)$ instead of $H/G$?
If the action is trivial, do you have $H^*(X,M)=H^*(H,M)$? (which does not look right, since $X=H\times BG$ in this case).

Comment: "an action of G on H" . Can I clarify what this means ? Is it just a $G$ action on $H$ thinking of $H$ as a manifold ?  Does the action preserve the group structure of $H$ ?  Is the action free, transitive etc ?  Thanks.

Comment: Xiao-Gang -- no worries; yes, yes and yes; if the action is trivial, i.e. via the trivial homomorphism $G\to H$, then $X$ is the quotient of $EH\times H$ by the trivial action of $G$. i.e., $H$ up to homotopy equivalence. I presume you are trying to understand a specific example, in which case it may be easier if you described it in your posting. Michael -- if $f:G\to H$ is a group homomorphism we can define an action of $G$ on $H$ by setting $h\cdot g=hf(g),h\in H,g\in G$.

Comment: algori: If $X$ is the quotient of $EH\times H$ by the trivial action of $G$, then $X \neq H\times BG$ (it seems). $H\times BG$
is the trivial bundle with fiber $H$ and base space $BG$,
a special case of my question.

Comment: Xiao-Gang -- indeed, as I say above, given a group homomorphism $f:G\to H$, the base is $BIm(f)$. If $f$ is an inclusion, it is $BG$. if the action is trivial it is the classifying space of the trivial group.

Comment: algori: do we know $H^*(X,M)$ even when $Im(f)$ is trivial but $G$ is not trivial. In this case, $H\times BIm(f) \neq H\times BG$.
The action of $G$ is trivial does not imply $BG$ is trivial.
Did I miss something simple?

Comment: Xiao-Gang -- if $X=(EH\times H)/G$ then it is homotopy equivalent to $H/Im(f)$.

Comment: algori: Yes, I agree that $(EH \times H)/G$ is homotopy equivalent to $H/Im(f)$. But is it homotopy equivalent to
$X$ which is defined as the fiber bundle with fiber $H$ and base space $BG$. In particular, when the action of $G$ is trivial,
$(EH \times H)/G$ is homotopy equivalent to $H$
which seems not  homotopy equivalent to $X=BG\times H$.

Comment: algori:  OK thanks.  So the $H$ bundle over $BG$ has classifying map $Bf : BG \to BH$.  I wasn't sure in the original posting what the relationship between $H$ and $G$ was.

Comment: XG -- what confuses me is that you talk about *the* bundle with fiber $H$ and base $BG$: as I say above, there are potentially *lots* of bundles with given base and fiber. You didn't specify one in your posting or comments, so I presumed you meant the one that comes from an action of $G$ on $H$. This bundle is the first that comes to my  mind but if you meant a different bundle, could you please specify which. And yes, $H$ is not the same as $H\times BG$, but this is no contractiction as when the action is trivial, again as I say above, the base is the $B$ of the trivial group, i.e. a point.

Comment: algori: I am sorry that I have not been clear. What I mean is that when the action of $G$ is trivial, $(EH \times H)/G$ is homotopy equivalent to $H$, which seems not homotopy equivalent to $X=BG\times H$ since $G$ can be any non-trivial group despite its action on $H$ is trivial.

Comment: Xiao-Gang -- no worries. Re the second sentence: yes, of course. Why does it look surprising? At this stage I really think it would help if you gave more details on the example(s?) you're interested in.